# Laravel belongsTo not working even with specific FK

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3.

I have 2 tables and 2 models (ad and category) :

```
Model ad :
----------------
class Ad extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ads';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ad_id';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'cat_id', 'cat_id');
    }
}
```

And

```
Model category :
-----------------
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';   

    public function ads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
    }
}
```

And my DB structure is :

```
ads:
    ad_id -
    ad_name
    ad_status
    cat_id

categoriess:
    cat_id -
    cat_name
```

I really don't know why, but I can't get the relation between using this (in my repository):

```
    return $this->model
        ->select('ad_id', 'ad_name')
        ->where('ad_status', '=', 1)
        ->with('category');
```

The query is fine, I got `ad` information, but the relation is empty. I checked, the `cat_id` exists in both tables.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `cat_id` key to `select()` to make it work:

```
return $this->model
    ->select('ad_id', 'ad_name', 'cat_id')
    ->where('ad_status', 1)
    ->with('category')
    ->get();
```

If you'll not add this key, relation will be always `null`. Also, use `get()` to get the data.

Comment: Oh wow ! thanks you man ! I didn't expect this one... I missed this one in the documention I guess.

Comment: @VincentDecaux you can also use `$this->model->with()`